# Datatable doesn't include multiple header rows into exported pdf file

Tags: datatable, export-to-pdf

Here is my HTML for datatable:

```
<table id="assessment-data-datatable-{{ $assessor->user_id }}">
  <thead>
    <tr class="success">
      <th>Assessee: {{ $assignment->assessee->fullname }}</th>
      <th>Assessor: {{ $assessor->fullname }}</th>
      <th>Status: {{ $assessor->pivot->status }} </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Parameter</th>
      <th>Assessment</th>
      <th>Provided on</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

And here is the js code:

```
    var dt = $('#assessment-data-datatable-' + assessorId).DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: '/assessment/' + assessmentId + '/' + assessorId + '/fetch',
                columns: [
                { data: 'parameter', defaultContent: 'N/A' },
                { data: 'assessment_value', defaultContent: 'N/A' },
                { data: 'created_at', defaultContent: 'N/A' }
                ],
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'pdf',
                    filename: assesseeName + ' assessment by ' +  assessorName,
                    exportoptions: {
                        header: true,
                        footer: true
                    }
                }
                ],
                destroy: true
            });
```

Above code works pretty well and it also exports the content into a pdf file. But into the exported pdf file, there is only second header row getting generated. Somehow the first row of the < header > gets excluded. I have also tried to move that row into < tfoot > and then export, but it also gets excluded there as well.

I think the issue here is that datatable only allows to export at max one row from the table header.

See here that how it exludes a row in header: (pdf screenshot)

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Parth Vora

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess feature to export multiple rows into header is not yet implemented in datatable itself.

See datattable owner answer here:
https://github.com/DataTables/Buttons/pull/55

And I found that why it was not exporting table footer.

This code:

```
buttons: [
  {
    extend: 'pdf',
    filename: assesseeName + ' assessment by ' +  assessorName,
    exportoptions: {
      header: true,
      footer: true
    }
  }
]
```

Should be like this:

```
buttons: [
  {
    extend: 'pdf',
    filename: assesseeName + ' assessment by ' +  assessorName,
  },
  header: true,
  footer: true
]
```

header and footer option should be on the outer object.