# Datatables - uncaught malformed table row a cell is undefined when trying to export to PDF

Tags: datatables, pdfmake

I have the below table,

```
<table id="dtBasicExample" class="table table-bordered" style="border : none;">
    <thead class="text-info" style="border : none;">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="16" style="border : none;"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2" class="text-right" style="border : none;">Date</th>
            <th colspan="14" style="border : none;">: <%=dstart%> - <%=dend%></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2" class="text-right" style="border:none;">Personel</th>
            <th colspan="14" style="border : none;">: <%=pers%></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2" class="text-right" style="border:none;">Grade</th>
            <th colspan="14" style="border : none;">: <%=grade%></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2" class="text-right" style="border:none;">Date Generated</th>
            <th colspan="14" style="border : none;">: <%=nowdate %></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="16" style="border-left : none; border-right: none;"/>
        </tr>
        <tr class="text-center">
            <th rowspan="3">Date</th>
            <th colspan="14">Number of Students</th>
            <th rowspan="3">Grand Total</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="text-center">
            <th colspan="7">Class A</th>
            <th colspan="7">Class B</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="text-center">
            <th style="width:6.2%;">Eng</th>
            <th style="width:6.2%;">BM</th>
            <th style="width:6.2%;">Man</th>
            <th style="width:6.2%;">SC</th>
            <th style="width:6.2%;">PHY</th>
            <th style="width:6.2%;">CHE</th>
            <th style="width:6.2%;">Sum</th>
            <th style="width:6.2%;">Eng</th>
            <th style="width:6.2%;">BM</th>
            <th style="width:6.2%;">Man</th>
            <th style="width:6.2%;">SC</th>
            <th style="width:6.2%;">PHY</th>
            <th style="width:6.2%;">CHE</th>
            <th style="width:6.2%;">Sum</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
...
```

Below is my js for my PDF exporting.

```
{
    action: function (e, dt, button, config) {
        showNotification('top', 'right', 'PDF exported sucessfully!');
        $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.pdfHtml5.action.call(this, e, dt, button, config);
    },
    extend: 'pdf',
    className: 'btn-info btnspaces',
    text: 'Export to PDF',
    filename: 'Students',
    orientation: 'landscape',
    pageSize: 'LEGAL',
    customize: function (pdf) {
        var firstHeaderRow = [];
        var secondHeaderRow = [];
        //11
        $('#dtBasicExample').find("thead>tr:nth-child(7)>th").each(
            function (index, element) {
            var colSpan = element.getAttribute("colspan");
            var rowSpan = element.getAttribute("rowspan");
            firstHeaderRow.push({
                text: element.innerHTML,
                style: "tableHeader",
                colSpan: colSpan,
                rowSpan: rowSpan
            });
            for (var i = 0; i < colSpan - 1; i++) {
                firstHeaderRow.push({});
            }
        });
        //10
        $('#dtBasicExample').find("thead>tr:nth-child(8)>th").each(
            function (index, element) {
            var colSpan = element.getAttribute("colspan");
            var rowSpan = element.getAttribute("rowspan");
            secondHeaderRow.push({
                text: element.innerHTML,
                style: "tableHeader",
                colSpan: colSpan,
                rowSpan: rowSpan
            });
            for (var i = 0; i < colSpan - 1; i++) {
                secondHeaderRow.push({});
            }
        });

        pdf.content[1].table.headerRows = 3;

        var objLayout = {};
        objLayout['hLineWidth'] = function (i) {
            return .5;
        };
        objLayout['vLineWidth'] = function (i) {
            return .5;
        };
        objLayout['hLineColor'] = function (i) {
            return 'black';
        };
        objLayout['vLineColor'] = function (i) {
            return 'black';
        };
        objLayout['paddingTop'] = function (i) {
            return 5;
        };
        objLayout['paddingBottom'] = function (i) {
            return 5;
        };
        objLayout['paddingLeft'] = function (i) {
            return 9;
        };
        objLayout['paddingRight'] = function (i) {
            return 9;
        };
        pdf.content[1].table.body.unshift(secondHeaderRow);
        pdf.content[1].table.body.unshift(firstHeaderRow);
        pdf.content[1].layout = objLayout;
    }
```

I have no issue exporting this to excel, but when I try to export it to PDF, it is giving the error

> uncaught malformed table row a cell is undefined

I tried to remove the colspan and manually add in `<td></td>` into the tables up to 16 cols, it works fine, but the date and grand total are in the last column instead of spanning throughout the 3 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To export the pdf header with `colSpan`, and `rowSpan`, empty cell should be padded for cell covered by span. The following code snippet will pad empty cell base on the `colSpan` and `rowSpan` of the head row(<th>).

---

**Due to [Download in Sandboxed Iframes (removed)](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5706745674465280), the button in the code snippet will not work, you may copy the following code to an html file, and open the file with a browser to see the effect.**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.21/b-1.6.2/b-flash-1.6.2/b-html5-1.6.2/b-print-1.6.2/datatables.min.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.21/b-1.6.2/b-flash-1.6.2/b-html5-1.6.2/b-print-1.6.2/datatables.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#dataTable').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [{
                extend: 'pdf',
                download: 'download',
                text: 'Export to PDF',
                filename: 'Students',
                orientation: 'landscape',
                pageSize: 'LEGAL',
                customize: function(pdfDocument) {
                    let headerRows = [];
                    let noOfColumn = 16;
                    let rowSpansOfColumns = [];
                    for (let i = 0; i < noOfColumn; i++) {
                        rowSpansOfColumns.push([]);
                    }
                    // only last header row is included, hence need to add back first 3 rows.
                    let noOfExtraHeaderRow = 3;
                    pdfDocument.content[1].table.headerRows = noOfExtraHeaderRow + 1;
                    // below loop convert html header to json, pad all covered by col/row span with {}
                    // i.e. there are 16 object in each row.
                    for (let i = 1; i <= noOfExtraHeaderRow; i++) {
                        let headerRow = [];
                        let colIdx = 0;
                        while (colIdx < rowSpansOfColumns.length && rowSpansOfColumns[colIdx].includes(i)) {
                            headerRow.push({});
                            colIdx++
                        }

                        $('#dataTable').find("thead>tr:nth-child(" + i + ")>th").each(
                            function(index, element) {
                                let colSpan = parseInt(element.getAttribute("colSpan"));
                                let rowSpan = parseInt(element.getAttribute("rowSpan"));
                                if (rowSpan > 1) {
                                    for (let col = colIdx; col < colIdx + colSpan; col++) {
                                        for (let row = i + 1; row < i + rowSpan; row++) {
                                            rowSpansOfColumns[col].push(row);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                headerRow.push({
                                    text: element.innerHTML,
                                    style: "tableHeader",
                                    colSpan: colSpan,
                                    rowSpan: rowSpan
                                });
                                colIdx++
                                for (let j = 0; j < colSpan - 1; j++) {
                                    headerRow.push({});
                                    colIdx++
                                }
                                while (colIdx < rowSpansOfColumns.length && rowSpansOfColumns[colIdx].includes(i)) {
                                    headerRow.push({});
                                    colIdx++
                                }
                            });
                        headerRows.push(headerRow);
                    }
                    pdfDocument.content[1].table.body = headerRows.concat(pdfDocument.content[1].table.body)
                }
            }]
        });
    });
</script>

<table id="dataTable" cellspacing="0" width="auto">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="16" style="border-left : none; border-right: none;"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="text-center">
      <th rowspan="3">Date</th>
      <th colspan="14">Number of Students</th>
      <th rowspan="3">Grand Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="text-center">
      <th colspan="7">Class A</th>
      <th colspan="7">Class B</th>
    </tr>

    <tr class="text-center">
      <th style="width:6.2%;">Eng</th>
      <th style="width:6.2%;">BM</th>
      <th style="width:6.2%;">Man</th>
      <th style="width:6.2%;">SC</th>
      <th style="width:6.2%;">PHY</th>
      <th style="width:6.2%;">CHE</th>
      <th style="width:6.2%;">Sum</th>
      <th style="width:6.2%;">Eng</th>
      <th style="width:6.2%;">BM</th>
      <th style="width:6.2%;">Man</th>
      <th style="width:6.2%;">SC</th>
      <th style="width:6.2%;">PHY</th>
      <th style="width:6.2%;">CHE</th>
      <th style="width:6.2%;">Sum</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>2020/10/11</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>60</td>
      <td>70</td>
      <td>80</td>
      <td>90</td>
      <td>85</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>60</td>
      <td>70</td>
      <td>80</td>
      <td>90</td>
      <td>85</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2020/11/11</td>
      <td>53</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>73</td>
      <td>83</td>
      <td>93</td>
      <td>83</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>53</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>73</td>
      <td>83</td>
      <td>93</td>
      <td>83</td>
      <td>26</td>
      <td>100</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Image of exported report

[image: pdf_withRowSpanHeader]

References:
[pdfmake documentation](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/document-definition-object/tables/)
[pdfmake playground](http://pdfmake.org/playground.html)

Comment: how do i make the code to select specific header to export? Say i want to select the 7th tr ``thead>tr:nth-child(7)>th`` , how do i do that?

Comment: You should state what you *actually* want when you post your question. I can't help without any details, and I think what you want now is quite different to your origin question.

Comment: I do not understand what I have to de based on your explication. English is not my mothertongue, but I have the same problem and I just don't get what you are trying to say that I have to do to make it work. Can you explain it more clearly please?

Comment: @YannickMussche, can you create a new question to put what you have so far?

Comment: @samabcde, I opened a new question with my code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73718032/error-error-uncaught-in-promise-malformed-table-row-a-cell-is-undefined